# jpackage not working on Windows 10 and JDK 16

Tags: java, kotlin, jpackage

trying to use `jpackage` for one of my projects, but does not work, crashing with a 103 error code.

Command:
`jpackage.exe  --main-jar evomaster.jar  --input core/target/ --type msi`

Error:

```
java.io.IOException: Command [C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\light.exe, -nologo, -spdb, -ext, WixUtilExtension, -out, C:\Users\arcur\WORK\code\EvoMaster\Main-1.0.msi, -sice:ICE27, -loc, C:\Users\arcur\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage3073169401587857747\config\MsiInstallerStrings_en.wxl, -cultures:en-us, C:\Users\arcur\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage3073169401587857747\wixobj\main.wixobj, C:\Users\arcur\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage3073169401587857747\wixobj\bundle.wixobj] in C:\Users\arcur\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage3073169401587857747\images\win-msi.image\Main exited with 103 code
```

JVM:
openjdk version "16" 2021-03-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 16+36)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 16+36, mixed mode, sharing)

OS Name Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
Version 10.0.18363 Build 18363

Any clue (of what I am doing wrong) or workaround (if someone has already faced this problem)?

### UPDATE:

after the suggestion of Jorn Vernee, I ran the `light` command directly, to see the error messages. it is full of:

```
C:\Users\arcur\WORK\code\EvoMaster\foo\config\bundle.wxf(14413) : error LGHT0103 : The system cannot find the file 'C:\Users\arcur\WORK\code\EvoMaster\foo\images\win-msi.image\Main\app\classes\org\evomaster\core\search\service\Archive$sortAndShrinkIfNeeded$inlined$thenBy$2.class'.
```

what all these error messages have in common is that they are related to `inlined` classes. The program is written in `Kotlin`, and the Jar is built with `maven-assembly-plugin`

Comment: Don't use Jdk 16 it is not the stable version I prefer to use jdk 11 or you can wait for jdk 17(the next stable version)

Comment: Could you please rerun `jpackage` with the `--temp somedir` option to dump temp files in a local directory, and then manually run the wix (`light`)  command from the error message to see if any more information is output? (for the latter step you'll have to change some of the paths in the wix command to point to the new temp directory)

Comment: thanks for the `--temp somedir` suggestion. the issue seems possibly related to Kotlin

Comment: @YeshwinVermaTheProgrammer  your comment is not really relevant. JDK 11 does not have `jpackage` (AFAIK), whereas JDK 17 is not out yet

Comment: @arcuri82 sorry my bad and thank you for informing me about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks to a discussion on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Kotlin/comments/noz4nv/jpackage_for_kotlin_applications/) I found a solution: you need to take your `app.jar` file out of the `target` folder, and put it in a folder (e.g., `foo`) that has only that file. then, use this new folder for the `--input` command.

The source of the problem seems `light.exe` not liking file paths that are too long... but all the other files under `target` are unnecessary when dealing with a uber-jar.